# features in GeoJson layer at a different angle as in Autocad

Tags: javascript, leaflet, turfjs

There are some lines in the plan, which are orthogonal to other lines.
However, when i convert the plan to geojson and display it in leaflet, the angles on the polylines in the first picture stay the same, but the angles on the second picture are not orthogonal anymore. I am using the default leaflet projection EPSG:4326, with the geojson converted from EPSG:2278 using ogr2ogr via commandline.

gist.github.com/pungiish/73fd38b372047364cb602e5c323b6 Here, if you zoom to Houston, you see the control lines, which don't look orthogonal either.

Here is a demo with the 2 features I measured in the screenshots, which are already converted from EPSG:2278 to EPSG:4326 via http://ogre.adc4gis.com/.
I uploaded the "original" CAD file with other features stripped here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xthw1iafnt4zkkx/Objects.dwg.dxf?dl=0

I've not added anything with which one could measure the angle in the demo, but you can see it looks a bit off.

So my question is, why are some of the features "distorted", which causes the angle between them not to be 90° anymore. I convert the coordinates correctly,..
Also, the rotation of the map ( features ) is not the same as when i open the dxf in autocad. In the picture, you can see the first object is rotated differently than when i open the geojson in leaflet ( reproduced in the demo ) and I don't understand why.

[image: autocad plan image]
[image: autocad plan image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Leaflet: How to display a Geojson file with AutoCAD data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62275657/leaflet-how-to-display-a-geojson-file-with-autocad-data)

Comment: Hey, I don't think so, the autocad crs is set to EPSG:2278 by the architect. Then, when converting from dxf to GeoJSON, i convert the coordinates to EPSG:4326. Reprojecting could scale the coords innacurately, but why would the first feature stay orthogonal and not the 2nd? I also tried using the L.CRS.Simple projection without reprojecting, but I couldn't find the features on the map, because the main features and the side features aren't that close, so setView(featureGroup.getBounds().getCenter()) doesn't zoom in on any of the features and it's far away from either.

Comment: ...and are you, by any chance, using proj4leaflet to display EPSG:2278 as EPSG:2278, or are you using Leaflet's default EPSG:3857? OTOH, a `setView(featureGroup.getBounds().getCenter())` on a `L.CRS.Simple` should work just fine, so consider putting up a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Same goes about shedding light about why only some of your data is [conformal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map_projection).

Comment: @IvanSanchez I am using the default EPSG:4326, with the geojson converted from EPSG:2278 using ogr2ogr via commandline. The setView didn't work, because the center of my featuregroup is between both features, but far away from either. https://gist.github.com/pungiish/73fd38b372047364cb602e5c323b6 Here, if you zoom to Houston, you see the control lines.  I also tried changing crs of the map to 2278 via proj4leaflet, but I got an error which lead to one of your answers, not to use other projections with leaflet, especially since geoJSON should conform to EPSG:4326. making a repro, thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to include any relevant info and clarifications (and make sure it's still a question); keeping stuff in long comments leads to confusion.

Comment: @IvanSanchez Edited and added a demo :).

Comment: It's better now :-) but your gist is not public (or so it seems). Be sure to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example BTW, make sure your example is *reproducible*.